# random selection of input pin

Tags: c++, random, pixel

I'm rather new at this and have hit a brick wall on somthing relatively simple. I have the following code attached. I would like input pin 8 to make a random selection of input pins 1-7 and have no idea to write it

```js
//          SONIC PROTOTYPE CODE         

//      Written by a complete amateur so take good care!

//  This is the code that will go in to my sonic screwdriver
//  Hardware includes Adafruit Feather 32U4, Music maker feather wing with amp Adafruit NeoPixel stick

#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN A1

const int sw1 = 2;     // This sets the name of the pins
const int sw2 = 3;
const int sw3 = 5;
const int sw4 = 6;
const int sw5 = 9;
const int sw6 = 10;
const int sw7 = 11;
const int sw8 = 12;

                    struct RGB {          //for fire this could posibly reside elsewhere in the script but I'm not too sure where
                    byte r;
                    byte g;
                    byte b;
                    };

                    RGB flameColors[] = {
                    //  { 226, 121, 35},  // Orange flame   /// select what colour fire you want here 
                    //  { 158, 8, 148},   // Purple flame 
                    //  { 74, 150, 12},   // Green flame
                    //  { 226, 15, 30}    // Red flame
                        { 15,50,148}      //Blue flame
                    };
                    //  Number of flame colors
                    int NUMBER_OF_COLORS = sizeof(flameColors) / sizeof(RGB);

                    //  Tracks the current color
                    int currentColorIndex = 0;

                    //  The button pin
                    const int buttonPin = 2;

                    //  Variable for reading the pushbutton status
                    int buttonState = 0;         

                    //  Tracking if it's ok to shift colors or not
                    bool okToChangeColors = true;




                    float redStates[8];               // I added these for twinkle
                    float blueStates[8];
                    float greenStates[8];
                    float fadeRate = 0.96;           

                    int totalLEDs = 8;                // added for tardis
                    int ledFadeTime = 5;


  Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(8, A1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

    // IMPORTANT: To reduce NeoPixel burnout risk, add 1000 uF capacitor across
    // pixel power leads, add 300 - 500 Ohm resistor on first pixel's data input
    // and minimize distance between Arduino and first pixel.  Avoid connecting
    // on a live circuit...if you must, connect GND first.


    void setup() 
  {

       pinMode(sw1, INPUT_PULLUP);    // the pins for your pull low are set here
       pinMode(sw2, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(sw3, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(sw4, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(sw5, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(sw6, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(sw7, INPUT_PULLUP);
       pinMode(sw8, INPUT_PULLUP);

      strip.begin();
      strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
    }

    void loop() 
  {
      // Some example procedures showing how to display to the pixels:
     // if (digitalRead(sw1) == LOW) colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50, sw1); // Red
     // if (digitalRead(sw7) == LOW) colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50, sw7); // Green
      if (digitalRead(sw2) == LOW) skip(150, 0, 150, 250, sw2);                                                                                                                                     
      if (digitalRead(sw1) == LOW) BouncingBalls(0, 0, 255, 3, sw1);                            
      if (digitalRead(sw3) == LOW) twinkle (sw3);                                       
    //  if (digitalRead(sw3) == LOW) colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50, sw3); // Blue
    //  if (digitalRead(sw4) == LOW) theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50, sw4); // White
    //  if (digitalRead(sw5) == LOW) theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 0), 50, sw5); // Red
     // if (digitalRead(sw6) == LOW) theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 127), 50, sw6); // Blue
      if (digitalRead(sw4) == LOW) rainbow(20, sw4);
      if (digitalRead(sw5) == LOW) rainbowCycle(20, sw5);
      if (digitalRead(sw6) == LOW) fire (sw6);
      if (digitalRead(sw7) == LOW) theaterChaseRainbow(50, sw7);
      //if (digitalRead(sw8) == LOW) tardis(sw8);
                  if (digitalRead(sw8) == LOW) scanner (sw8);                                                                                     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest change from your code is make a function that accepts the pin-number and call that function if in the loop-function you detect that the pin is low.  Inside the new function, use a switch to map the pin number to the needed action.  In case of pin 8, call the function with the randomly chosen pin number.

For getting a random number, it is easiest to select from from a contiguous range. If this is not possible, you might want to map the random number to scattered values via an array: `std::array<4> mapping{ 2, 7, 12, 103 };` to choose between those numbers.

```
void doAction(int pin)
{
    switch (pin)
    {
        case 2: skip(150, 0, 150, 250, sw2); return;
        ...
    }
}

void loop(std::uniform_int_distribution<>& dis, std::mt19937& gen) 
{
    if (digitalRead(sw2) == LOW) doAction(2);
    ...
    if (digitalRead(sw8) == LOW) doAction(dis(gen));
}                       

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 7);

    while (true)
    {
        loop(dis, gen);
    }
}
```

There are better ways to map actions to pins but they require more changes: mapping detected pin to pin number, `std::map<int,std::function<void(int)>` with lambdas,...

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time out to show me how I really appreciate it... I can't belive how negative and rude some people are, we all had to start somewhere right?

Comment: You're welcome. The most negative feedback is probably for [not asking an actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and for not showing [a (preferably working) example that shows the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of dumping the complete code.  Don't take it too personally but take it into account for the next question.

Comment: Hello. Me again, I had a good go at trying to follow your advice and I merged your changes into my script however I could not get them to work

Comment: I could not include all the code as it is to big so please find it in https://github.com/JoleneHachers/Sonic-Screwdriver/tree/master/sonic_proto_2_0_2_not_working. there are errors around the void loop(std::uniform_int_distribution<>& dis, std::mt19937& gen) area. I feel maybee I should of customised these? Any advice I would be extreamly greatful

Comment: You have to add `include <random>` to use these, see also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Also, this is c++11, for older compilers see std::srand, std::rand from <cstdlib>, for an example, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm